# Sometimes FTP fails

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

My project has to upload and download lot of files from and to Unix server using ftp in my windows aoolication.
my code is like this

```
   ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(reviewfilepath);

                    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);                        
                    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                    ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
                    ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
                    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                     ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                     FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(reviewsourcewordpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                     byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int bytesSent1 = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    try
                    {
                        while (bytesSent1 != 0)
                        {
                            ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent1);
                            bytesSent1 = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        }
                        string path = cls_appvars.Set_App_Path + cls_appvars.Set_Log_dir + "SystemLog.txt";
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, System.DateTime.Now + "***ftp_documents() in cls_accdet***" + jobid + "_review ----- File uploaded Sucessfully" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                    /* Resource Cleanup */
                    localFileStream.Close();
                    ftpStream.Close();
                    ftpRequest = null;
```

the issue is few times ftp failes and getting the exception

```
     System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
 at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

I disabled firewall in client machine, enabled ftp.exe and given full rights for the user, but still am getting the exception.

Thanks,

Suressh

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the `FtpWebRequest` timeout, for example

```
ftpRequest.Timeout = 30000 // in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

FTP sometimes fail due to packet drop, some connections limits or other technical reasons, it will happen. If your App relies on that transfer, code some retry logic before returning from that call. Put your request into a loop that returns the content on success or rethrows the exception on the third fail.

Comment: thanks stephan, i already ping the server for whole day there is no failure, am using retry mechanism the issue with that is it blocks further ftp uploads and downloads.. will check on rest of your suggestions..

Comment: A good ping does not guarantee a good ftp transfer, I'm afraid you have to pool your transfers or use threads to reduce blocking : /

Comment: Thanks for you advise stephan, let me try and inform you the result. another point that i want to add is each ftp process is a individual backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config file of your porject.

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
        </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```